# How do I use the WFP layer ALE_BIND_REDIRECT?

Tags: windows, networking, routes, wfp

I cannot find any example code on how to use the `ALE_BIND_REDIRECT` Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) layer.

I do need to rewrite source IPs, but I cannot figure out how to use this layer. Can someone explain how to achieve this using the `ALE_BIND_REDIRECT` layer?